# Can't connect to WCF service from client

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

i get this error while trying to access a WCF service hosted in iis (locally) from a c# client:

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'X' and contract 'Contract
>   Name' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be
>   because no configuration file was found for your application, or
>   because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the
>   client element.

This is the client's app.config (it is a NUnit fixture just to test connection):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MyWs" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
           <endpoint address="https://localhost/MyWs/MyWs.svc"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MyWs"
                    contract="MyServiceSvc.IMyWs"
                    name="BasicHttpBinding_MyWs" />
        </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

If i browse

```
https://localhost/MyWs/MyWs.svc?wsdl
```

i get correct output so the server part is working fine.
Moreover, i can test my ws with soapUI so the problem must be in the client, maybe in the app.config.

My client code, just in case someone wants tolook at it:

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyWsProxyFixture
    {
        private readonly MyWsClient _client = new MyWsClient();

        [Test]
        public void ProxyCreation()
        {
            Assert.IsNotNull(_client);
        }

        //More tests here
}
```

Even funnier, the exact same configuration and client works in another machine. Yes it is true. I cannot believe it myself but so it is.

Can you give some hints or suggestions to work this out?
Thanks!

PS: the service reference in the client is fine.

Comment: pls provide ur solution structure so that i can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: My solution: 1 wcf service that uses other various components (class library projects) and a class library project for the client

Comment: Can you post your client code? Also are you using Add Service Reference of the WCF service or did you generate a proxy from the WSDL and included it in the client project? Also in the client config i can see the contract value has a namespace and hope the interface is in the same namespace in the client project as well

Comment: see my edit. Yes namespace in server and client is the same. Also, it doesn't seem to matter if i change it... it always give me the same exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out that the problem was not in the App.config at all.
In fact, the very same App.config was working right in another machine.
The problem was with Nunit. By default, it uses a "Shadow copy" setting that copyes all dlls in a temp folder and executes the binary from there. What i cannot understan is why it does copy dlls but not .config. It just make no sense!
After i set shadow copy to false it started working in my machine too.

PS: The client wa working int other machine because the environment was running under Resharper, which turns off by default the shadow copy.
It makes sense now!

Hope this helps someone with same stupid problem

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see it can be a multiple projects config problem:
If you have multiple projects in your solution then you have to put that configuration file in  the config of the particular project that is consuming wcf service.
Suppose you have 2 projects then there will be 2 corresponding config files.

Comment: the app.config file is in the same project. Do you mean the web.config file? However, i just have 1 client project

Comment: Have u checked that all contracts has been set properly?

Comment: Yes, as the question says, references are fine. The very same configuration is working in another machine